# Как правильно составить POST запрос с помощью cURL для добавления оригинального текста в вебмастер.яндекс?

Tags: php, http, curl, яндекс-вебмастер

уважаемое сообщество.
Собственно задача такая - есть какой-то текст, мне его нужно добавить в "Оригинальные тексты" в яндексе.
Стараюсь разобраться с curl и яндекс api (читал документацию яндекса для разработчиков, читал документацию по curl, проходил уроки по curl).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать запросы с помощью curl при определенных условиях, которые задаются в документации. Зачастую не понимаю, что именно нужно сделать и как составить запрос. Или почитать как это делать. Самые банальные и поверхностные уроки и прочее я начитался, никакой конкретики и понимания они толком не дают, чтобы с них я мог пойти и работать с яндекс api вот так с ходу.

На данный момент я получил token и user_id. Но как составить запросы дальше не понимаю, хотя и всё указано в [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/webmaster/doc/dg/reference/host-original-texts-post-docpage/).

Не очень понимаю:

1. Какие стандартные curl_setopt должны быть у запроса?
2. Что означает передайте в теле запроса основной текст. Как это сделать?
3. Вообще, что конкретно можно и нужно почитать, чтобы уже понять как это всё работает и как и что составлять, если вдруг буду работать с другими api.

Код:

```
  $client_id = "строка";
  $client_secret = "строка";

  if (!isset($_GET["code"])) {
    Header("Location: https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=".$client_id);
    die();
  }


  $result=$this->postKeys("https://oauth.yandex.ru/token",
    array(
      'grant_type'=> 'authorization_code', 
      'code'=> $_GET["code"], 
      'client_id'=>$client_id,
      'client_secret'=>$client_secret
      ),
    array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    );

  //Получение token'а
  if ($result["code"]==200) 
  {
    $result["response"]=json_decode($result["response"],true);
    $token=$result["response"]["access_token"];
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Код ошибки: ".$result["code"];
  }

  //Получение user_id
  $result=$this->getStat(
    'https://api.webmaster.yandex.net/v3/user/', 
    array('Authorization: OAuth '.$token)
  );
  $result["response"]=json_decode($result["response"],true);
  $user_id=$result["response"]["user_id"];

  //Отправка текста на яндекс
  $result=$this->postArticle(
    "POST https://api.webmaster.yandex.net/v3/user/$user_id/hosts/$client_id/original-texts/",
    array(
      'content' => "asdfsdfwaedfadsads"
      ),
    array('Authorization: OAuth '.$token,'Content-type: application/xml')
    );
  dd($result);
  echo "Код: ".$result["code"];


  return view('api');
}

//Получение токена
public function postKeys($url,$peremen,$headers) 
{
  $post_arr=array();
  foreach ($peremen as $key=>$value) {
    $post_arr[]=$key."=".$value;
    }
  $data=implode('&',$post_arr);
  
  $handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  $response=curl_exec($handle);
  $code=curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  return array("code"=>$code,"response"=>$response);
}

//Получение user_id
public function getStat($url,$headers) {
  $handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response=curl_exec($handle);
  $code=curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  return array("code"=>$code,"response"=>$response);
}

//Отправка текста в яндекс "Оригинальные тексты"
public function postArticle($url,$peremen,$headers)
{
  $data=json_encode($peremen)

  $handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  $response=curl_exec($handle);
  $code=curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  return array("code"=>$code,"response"=>$response);
}
```

Comment: а есть какие конкретные непонятные моменты, т.е. что вы не понимаете?